# How to align multiple symbols for a long equation?

Tags: equations, amsmath, align, mactex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xfrac, array, tabu, multirow, graphicx, setspace, dcolumn, tikz}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
%the argument for d specifies the maximum number of decimal places
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\bar{x}&=7+(2\times9) + (2\times10) + (4\times11) + (6\times12) + (7\times14)\\ 
&+(2\times15) + (3\times16) + 17 + 18 + 19\\
\bar{x}&=14
 \end{align} 
\end{document}
```

I was looking long and hard for an answer, I believe `{alignat*}` is capable to do what I want, I just can't figure out how. I want the too long equation to align as follows: 1st and 3rd row the `=` should be aligned. But I also want the 1st and 2nd row to be aligned where the first `+` comes in.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an `aligned` as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \bar{x}&=\!
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    7&+(2\times9) + (2\times10) + (4\times11) + (6\times12) + (7\times14)\\
    &+(2\times15) + (3\times16) + 17 + 18 + 19\\
  \end{aligned}\\
  \bar{x}&=14
\end{align} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `\hphantom` command is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent Either
\begin{align}
  \bar{x} &= 7 + (2\times9) + (2\times10) + (4\times11) + (6\times12) + (7\times14)\notag\\
          &\hphantom{{}= 7} + (2\times15) + (3\times16) + 17 + 18 + 19\\
  \bar{x} &= 14
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
 \begin{split}
  \bar{x} &= 7 + (2\times9) + (2\times10) + (4\times11) + (6\times12) + (7\times14)\\
          &\hphantom{{}= 7} + (2\times15) + (3\times16) + 17 + 18 + 19
 \end{split}\\
  \bar{x} &= 14
\end{align}
is probably what you are looking for.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

P.S. Remember `{}` before `=` to get the correct horizontal spacing.

Comment: `\hphantom` is in the `TeX` core AFAIR, it has nothiong to do with mathtools.

Comment: I see; I'll change my comment accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps the first two lines could be wrapped inside a `split` environment, so the first expression receives just one number instead of the current two numbers (which are odd).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes.... or just use a `\notag` at the end of the first line.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg there's a difference, though: using `split` the number will be vertically centered between the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in the `breqn` package, which does this automatically and gets the line numbers sorted out too (moving them out the way of long lines, for example).

It generally breaks equations quite well, but it does not play nicely with some other packages: sansmath, for example, because they both hack deep into the internals of the maths system.